# If a 4-bit binary digit in 2's Complement form is stored in 8 bits how is it represented?

Tags: digital-logic, binary

I am quite new to Digital Logic. I got this doubt while solving a problem.

If a 4 bit binary digit in 2's complement e.g. X3 X2 X1 X0 is stored in an 8 bit space what will be the representation in those 8 bits.

As far as i know, The MSB in 2's complement form is the sign bit.

So if e.g **X3 X2 X1 X0 = 0 0 0 0** then **X7 X6 X5 X4 X3 X2 X1 X0 = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0**

if e.g **X3 X2 X1 X0 = 1 1 0 1** then **X7 X6 X5 X4 X3 X2 X1 X0 = 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1**

Could you generalize the way in which we will represent 4 bits in 2's complement to 8 bits?

Comment: Msb /sign bit ie X3 is copied into higher nibble this is called sign bit extension.

Comment: It does depend on the arithmetic you plan to do with it.  If you have a 4 bit or 8bit possibly binary or BCD arithmetic logic unit you will have to behave differently.  If you have a hardware platform in mind please elaborate.

Comment: How is the 4-bit value being "stored in an 8 bit space"? By software? In an HDL? How has the 4-bit value been **declared**? Signed? Unsigned? Bit vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2's complement form, a positive number stored in 8 bits is represented as 0x00 to 0x7F (0 to 127 in decimal).

Negative numbers range from 0xFF to 0x80 (-1 to -128 in decimal).

For example -1 is the 1's complement of 0x01 = 0xFE (8 bits) , with 0x01 added = 0xFF.

You obviously need 5 bits to represent a signed decimal digit (there are 19 possibilities), and effectively the 5th bit (bit 4 as we usually count it) gets copied into bits 5, 6 and 7. So -9 is the complement of 0x09 = 0xF6, plus 1 = 0xF7.

Similarly, if you were representing the single signed digit in a 32-bit wide variable, 1 would be 0x00000001 and -1 would be 0xFFFFFFFF (and -9 would be 0xFFFFFFF7).

Comment: So, if the 4 bits contain X3 X2 X1 X0 what will the 8 bits contain?

Comment: If it is only 4 bits 2's complement, it can only represent -8 to +7. Just copy X3 to the leftmost 4 bits.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how the source value should be interpreted.

- If the 4 bits are signed then yes, the MS bit gets replicated.
- But if the 4 bits are unsigned, the MS bits are set to zero.

I write a lot of HDL (Verilog) code and I estimate that about 90% of the numbers I deal with are unsigned.

Comment: It is signed. So how will it get represented? Could you generalize it pls? Like, should the value stored in 8 bits be 0000X3X2X1X0 OR 1111X3X2X1X0 for example